# Unable to connect EC2 instance using ssh command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, public-key

I'm new on using EC2 and meet a unsolvable issue. I follow the guideline to set up the EC2 instance, and use ssh to connect.

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/EC2MyKeyPair.pem ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I have changed the permission of pem file to 400

```
chmod 400 ~/.ssh/EC2MyKeyPair.pem
```

Also, I have tried to change username to admin, ubuntu, ... But all the username listed in guideline are fail.

I tried to read the debug log, but unable to find the problem. It seems the username "ec2-user" is correct, is it fine is "key_load_public" is not found? And what is the problem cause the connection fail?

Thanks all!

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxx/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/EC2MyKeyPair.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/xxx/.ssh/EC2MyKeyPair.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 18.223.29.186
debug1: Host 'ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/EC2MyKeyPair.pem (0x0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/xxx/.ssh/EC2MyKeyPair.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:XR1+xxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

---

Updated:
For more information, my files under ~/.ssh

```
drwx------    7 xxx  staff   224 Oct 28 16:15 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 100 xxx  staff  3200 Oct 28 16:50 ..
-r--------@   1 xxx  staff  1696 Oct 28 16:14 EC2MyKeyPair.pem
-rw-r--r--    1 xxx  staff   451 Dec 19  2016 config
-r--------    1 xxx  staff  1675 Apr 28  2015 id_rsa
-r--------    1 xxx  staff   405 Apr 28  2015 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 xxx  staff  4496 Oct 28 16:20 known_hosts
```

I read some references, their log contains accessing id_rsa, but i don't know why my log does not....

Comment: Which AMI did you choose when launching the instance? Which keypair did you select when launching the instance, and does it match the `EC2MyKeyPair.pem` file?

Comment: I choose the amazon Linux instance, the username should be ec2-user according to the document, but i have tried the other options such as admin, ubuntu etc, all of them are not work.

Comment: I access NETWORK & SECURITY -> key pairs, and create key pair by clicking "Create key pairs", input a name and download pem file, then move it to ~/.ssh/ path.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Anything should i do to match the instance with the pem file? Many thanks!

Comment: When you launched the EC2 instance, did you select this keypair? Or was the keypair created _after_ the instance was launched?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I use ssh command with -i EC2MyKeyPair.pem, it should be correct key pair, but it is created after instance launched... How to link the pem file with launched instance? Thanks!

Comment: Given that you used Amazon Linux, then the username is correctly `ec2-user`. It is claiming that the keypairs do not match. As an experiment, I suggest launching another instance and confirming that they keypair is selected on launch, they try to login.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Success! Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Excuse me another question I want to know, how can i add another key pair to the instance if i allow another developer to access the server? And how to inactivate the key pair to stop another developer accessing the server? Thanks!

Comment: It is just standard Linux. When you login to a Linux computer, it looks in ~.ssh/authorized_keys — if it contains the public half of a keypair that matches the private half being used to login, then it permits the login. Therefore, you can add/remove public keys in that file.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sorry i'm not familiar with Linux and wanna ask more. For the above case, EC2MyKeyPair.pem is a private key and it is downloaded to my computer, the public key is set to aws console automatically. As i known that, it should be unique pair. If i update the pem file, will the key pair become unmatch?

Comment: [understanding public key private key concepts » Blake Smith](http://blakesmith.me/2010/02/08/understanding-public-key-private-key-concepts.html) and [SSH Essentials: Working with SSH Servers, Clients, and Keys | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-essentials-working-with-ssh-servers-clients-and-keys)